# Multiple start destination to one final destination jetpack navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to send data from multiple fragments and multiple recycler views to 1 WebView/ specific fragment from my ListAdapter View Holder using jetpack navigation. is this possible?

EX: I click on an item in my recycler view from the breaking news fragment it sends me to the webview with the specific article as a bundle.

I can also switch to my search news article using my bottom nav menu and click on it through there and the same functionality of opening it in a webview would happen aswell.

[link to repo](https://github.com/Kariizma/MVVMNewsApp)

my Adapter Class

```
class NewsAdapter : ListAdapter<Article,NewsAdapter.ArticleViewHolder>(DiffCallBack)
{

    companion object DiffCallBack: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem.url == newItem.url
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    class ArticleViewHolder(private val binding: ItemArticlePreviewBinding):
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(article: Article) {
            Glide.with(itemView).load(article.urlToImage).into(binding.ivArticleImage)
            binding.tvSource.text = article.source.name
            binding.tvTitle.text = article.title
            binding.tvDescription.text = article.description
            binding.tvPublishedAt.text = article.publishedAt
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                Log.d("OnClick on Item works:", " ${article.source.name}: ${article.url}")
                //conditional to be able to use searchNews or savedNews Fragment aswell[![enter image description here][1]][1]
it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_breakingNewsFragment_to_articleFragment,Bundle().apply {
                    putSerializable("article",article)
                })
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ArticleViewHolder {
        return ArticleViewHolder(ItemArticlePreviewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(item)
    }


}
```

nav_graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/news_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/breakingNewsFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/breakingNewsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.mvvmnewsapp.ui.fragments.BreakingNewsFragment"
        android:label="BreakingNewsFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_breakingNewsFragment_to_articleFragment"
            app:destination="@id/articleFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
        <argument
            android:name="article"
            app:argType="com.example.mvvmnewsapp.ui.model.Article" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/savedNewsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.mvvmnewsapp.ui.fragments.SavedNewsFragment"
        android:label="SavedNewsFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_savedNewsFragment_to_articleFragment"
            app:destination="@id/articleFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
        <argument
            android:name="article"
            app:argType="com.example.mvvmnewsapp.ui.model.Article" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/searchNewsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.mvvmnewsapp.ui.fragments.SearchNewsFragment"
        android:label="SearchNewsFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_searchNewsFragment_to_articleFragment"
            app:destination="@id/articleFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
        <argument
            android:name="article"
            app:argType="com.example.mvvmnewsapp.ui.model.Article" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/articleFragment"
        android:name="com.example.mvvmnewsapp.ui.fragments.ArticleFragment"
        android:label="ArticleFragment" />
</navigation>
```